# Integrate TFS with outlook without third party tools

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, outlook, project-management, project-server

I want to expose/edit tasks through Outlook that's stored in TFS. 
Is that possible without third party tools?

Maybe using SharePoint.

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more information than this... What version of TFS, what version of SharePoint, what version of Outlook? Why not use freely available third party tools? TFS 2010 has built in integration with Outlook.

Comment: well, it's the latest of all products... 2010

Answer (score 0):

TFS doesn't offer this feature out of the box, so by definition you'd have to use a third-party product like [TeamLook](http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teamlook/features/microsoft-outlook-integration.aspx) or build something yourself. Brian Harry mentions some other options [on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2009/03/17/tfs-outlook-add-ins.aspx).